# how to make a table from .txtfile without hard coding the value and how to min and max of the list

Tags: python-3.x

so far this what i have,

```
def List():
    bad_filename = True
    while bad_filename == True:
        try:
            filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
            fp = open(filename, "r")
            for f_line in fp:
                b=(f_line.strip('\n').split(','))
                l=[float(v) for v in b]
                l=[]
                for v in b:
                    l.append(float(v))
                print (l,end=" ")

            bad_filename = False
        except IOError:
            print("Error: The file was not found: ", filename)

def tab():
    A=()
    print_str = "|{:^5s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s}| {:^10s} |{:^10s}|".format("Name","A", "B","C","D","E")
    hline = "-" * len(print_str)
    lline="-"*len(print_str)
    print(hline)
    print(print_str)
    print(lline)
    format_str= "|{:>5s} |{:^10.2f}  |{:^10.2f} |{:^10.2f}  |{:>10f}|"
    print_str= format_str.format('1',1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00)
    print (print_str)
    print_str=format_str.format('2',6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,0.00)
    print(print_str)
    print_str=format_str.format('3',1.1,2.2,3.3,0.1,0.3)
    print(print_str)

List()
tab()
```

my problem starts when the user change the data in .txtfile because i hardcoded the number to print table and i also need to make an array so i can get a min max value out of the list.

instead of hard code value like this ('1',1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00)
i want it to read from .txt file and generate the table in the txt file i have stored data in the desktop
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,0
1.10,2.20,3.30,0.10,0.30

Comment: i did the first function because i need to get a list out of them and use them to get min, max and average.

Comment: i know i use main at the top for the function name but when i change the name and create a new main to print both the function i get error and i can't think any further, any help

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try...

First, reformat your `List()` function to get rid of extra code and to **return** a list, instead of printing it, so you can then process it...

```
def GenList():
    bad_filename = True
    while bad_filename == True:
        try:
            filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
            fp = open(filename, "r")
            l = []

            for f_line in fp:
                rownum += 1
                b = f_line.strip('\n').split(',')
                l.append([float(v) for v in b])
            fp.close()
            bad_filename = False
            return l    
        except IOError:
            print("Error: The file was not found: ", filename)
```

Now call that function to get your lists:

```
MyList = GenList()
```

For your other printing function, make it take an "argument" as input (this list) and use that in your subsequent `.format()` statements:

```
def MakeTable(InputList):
    format_str= "|{:>5s} |{:^10.2f}  |{:^10.2f} |{:^10.2f}  |{:>10f}|"
    print("The max of the list is {0} and the min is {1}".format(max(InputList),min(InputList)) )
    # etc....
```

Comment: thank you but i need to print the table which i was able to i need to ask the user if they want to min or max of either column or row  -----------------------------------------------
|     |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1 | 1.00  | 2.00  | 3.00  | 4.00  | 5.00  |
|   2 | 6.00  | 7.00  | 8.00  | 9.00  | 0.00  |
|   3 | 1.10  | 2.20  | 3.30  | 0.10  | 0.30  |
for example if the user want to get the max on the row of 1 it should print 5 and if he want to min on b the min should be 2.

Comment: this is what i did to call the both the function but its not working  only thing it does is ask for the filename and end the programm          def main():
    filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
    #MyList = GenList()
    print (Genlist(l))
    print (MakeList(InputList))
    
main()